# Visual Studio Online - Load Testing API Error

Tags: azure, load-testing, azure-devops

I am using Visual Studio Online to run the Load Tests. Lately we started using the Load Test service API to run the load tests instead of running them manually.

Everything works perfectly. However, when the test runs gets completed and we download the results file from results API `/_apis/clt/testruns/<ID>/results`, the zip file gets downloaded correctly. However, after download is complete, we are unable to unzip it, we get an error saying that it is not a valid archive.

On the other hand if we open the test run in Visual Studio Load Test manager, it downloads the report correctly. We are not sure what compression does it use, is there any special program/logic that can be used to extract its contents, etc.

Comment: Which visual studio IDE you are using?